# File-based database asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, database, text

Is there some kind of simple database system that uses simple text or xml files for data storage? I just need some basic functionality like update,delete, insert, simple constraints and relations.

For the project that I have now using SQL Server would be too heavyweight and I have never really liked it anyway.

Comment: microsoft access just works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is: [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) :)

There is ADO Provider:
http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=2

There is article on that:
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Using-SQLite-for-Simple-Database-Storage/

Comment: Nice, but can I integrate this into my ASP.net application? I am using shared hosting, does the server need to have it installed?

Comment: @diamandiev: No there is no need. You can use sqlite on your shared host.

Comment: How does this work then? If the server does not have the dll's do I need to just add them to the Bin folder?

Comment: Yes and this is just beautiful :)

Answer (score 2):

The DataSet from the .NET Framework is also an option. See [DataSets, DataTables, and DataViews (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: How about persisting the data?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical:

- [**XML as Data Source**](http://script.wareseeker.com/ASP/xml-as-data-source.zip/2688)
- [**Manipulate XML File Data Using
  C#**](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3489611/Manipulate-XML-File-Data-Using-C.htm)

These projects will give you an idea

- [**Roll Your Own Database**](http://en.csharp-online.net/Working_with_Data%E2%80%94Roll_Your_Own_Database)
- [**Using XML as Database with Dataset**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/XMLData.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

SqlCompact is a great option for this. There is no engine or setup, just include the .dll and you can create a database on the fly.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DC614AEE-7E1C-4881-9C32-3A6CE53384D9&displaylang=en

-- EDIT: like @MathewMartin said: SqlCompact 4.0 is intended to be a web database and allows multiple connections.

Comment: There is an override for it though.     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", True)

Comment: For future readers, SQL Compact is entirely OK for ASP.NET if it version 4.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a good option.

Since your using .net though, i'd consider just using xml and LINQ to XML, it's very sql like in many ways.

Comment: -1: It's like SQL, except for "some basic functionality like update,delete, insert, simple constraints and relations".

Comment: @john, only relational constraints are missing, everything else is possible in a simple and expressive manner.

Comment: sorry, insert, update and delete are not "simple and expressive", as it's necessary to layer these concepts onto a sequential file format.

Comment: expressive might be a stretch, but it's certainly simple imo!

Answer (score 0):

Check this Stack Overflow question:  **[Free portable database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557632/free-portable-database)**

There you will find list of "lightweight" databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer **object database**, then consider using [NDatabase](https://ndatabase.codeplex.com/).