# What database can I use that does not need an application to be installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi I am creating a windows application and I need to select a database. I dont want to go out and install sql server express for every person who uses my application.

What database can I use that does not need an application to be installed. I would like to have a database for each customer that is stored locally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free portable database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557632/free-portable-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/). It's free and you just have to distribute a dll
It allows you to manage up to 14 terabytes sized DBs (http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: I would use something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what you wanted to use it for, if you just want one database for each user then I would look at using SQLite

If you need one database for every user that SQL server installed on a remote server would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) rocks in these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use : [SQL Light](http://www.blurtit.com/q933093.html) database might resolve your problem.

[Limits In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: what is the max size of a sql lite and can I use petapoco?

Comment: @user351709 - have look to this for limits http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html or click on second link of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use either [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure about SQL Lite, but for distribution, you can just xcopy the SQL server CE over during an install. can't get easier than that. However, there are some restrictions (no stored procedures, i think). It is also integrated nicely into visual studio, if thats your bag.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think of using SQLite. It is serverless and requires no preconfiguration on the users part. Each database is simply kept as a single file. Read this [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html)