# c# - How can I setup own MySQL database to my users' own pc

Tags: c#, mysql, database, heidisql

I'm working on a program that include user log-in and sign-up. I'm using MySQL with HeidiSQL app which is free. I can use my app in my own pc but when I start it an another pc it doesn't even connect to database.
I want to make a setup program which contains my app and mysql installer. I want to setup mysql to my customers' computer so they can all have their own databases and connect to them.  How can i achieve this?

My connection string is:

```
public MySqlConnection mysqlbaglan = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=x;Uid=root;Pwd='';");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rethink your architecture.
You could try SQLite which is portable and does not need installation as a server.

Check out this relevant [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557632/free-portable-database).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you should:

- create setup of your app (you van use installshield, or wix, or another setup manager (http://wixtoolset.org/, http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php))
- in that setup, you should configure a database deployment to your clients, i.e., verify if client as mysql installed, if not, your setup should install (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-windows-quick.html). After that, you just run your sql scripts to generate database in your client (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-sql-query-directly-on-the-command-line/).
- make sure your connection string is valid